# PHP openssl Error create Certificate NOT self signed

Tags: php, openssl, certificate, ca

i want to create a certificate NOT self signed, similar CA. I 've tried this code

```
<?php
// Supposons que ce script est configuré pour recevoir des CSR qui ont
// été collés dans un champ textarea depuis une autre page
 
$csrdata ="client.crt";

// Nous allons signer la requête avec notre propre certificat, en tant
// qu'"autorité de certification". Vous pouvez utiliser n'importe quel
// certificat pour en signer un autre, mais le processus est inutile à moins
// que le certificat de signature n'ait la confiance des utilisateurs
// qui utiliseront le nouveau certificat signé.

// Nous avons besoin de notre certificat et de la clé privée
$cacert = "CA.crt";
$privkey = array("CA.key", "la_cle_secrete_de_votre_certificat");

$usercert = openssl_csr_sign($csrdata, $cacert, $privkey, 365);

// Affichons maintenant le certificat généré, de façon à ce que l'utilisateur
// puisse le copier/coller dans sa configuration locale (comme un
// fichier qui contient les certificats de son serveur SSL)
openssl_x509_export($usercert, $certout);
echo "<br>IL CERTIFICATO FINALE è :<br> $certout";

// Affiche toutes les erreurs survenues
while (($e = openssl_error_string()) !== false) {
    echo $e . "\n";
}
?>
```

But i receive the error error:

> 0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line.

Someone know the solution?

Comment: Per [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-sign.php) if you're specifying a file path it needs to start with `file://`.

Comment: you have reason Sammitch , but there is sure anothere error because also with your advice i obtain the same error

Comment: [link](https://www.noirsolutions.net/esempi/php/CRT/client.crt) client.crt

Comment: [link](https://www.noirsolutions.net/esempi/php/CRT/CA.crt) CA.crt

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved. This is the solution of the problem to create a Certificate similar CA

```
<?php

$csrdata ="file://client.csr";
$cacert = "file://CA.crt";
$privkey = array("file://CA.key", "la_cle_secrete_de_votre_certificat");

$usercert = openssl_csr_sign($csrdata, $cacert, $privkey, 365);

openssl_x509_export($usercert, $certout);
echo "<br>FINAL RESULT :<br> $certout";

// Affiche toutes les erreurs survenues
while (($e = openssl_error_string()) !== false) {
    echo $e . "\n";
}
?>
```